# Using Google Analytics to track clicks

Tags: google-analytics

Very simple scenario: I simply wish to track, using google analytics, every instance that a visitor of my site clicks on a link to an external website. I've done this using event tracking to the best of my understanding, but when I then click on the link, I don't see any tracking in the google analytics report.

I'm wondering if:
(a) there is something wrong with my code;
(b) I'm not looking in the right place in my google analytics account;
(c) both

Below is my entire page in its entirety, subsitituting 111111111 for the actual account id:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

    <body>
        <script>
            (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
                i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
                a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
                a.async = 1;
                a.src = g;
                m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
            })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-1111111111-1', 'mysite.com');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1111111111-1']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function () {
                var ga = document.createElement('script');
                ga.type = 'text/javascript';
                ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
        </script> <a target="_blank" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links', 'Click', 'CNN']);"
        href="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</a>
        <br/>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The start of your problems would be that you mix two different versions of analytics code (look up the difference between ga.js and analytics.js).

Answer (score 1):

There are few things wrong with your code:

## Analytics version

You're mixing up the old `ga.js` and the newer `analytics.js`

Just use only the newer `analytics.js`

## Race condition

You're tracking the event onClick, but at this point, the browser's already leaving the page and the request may not go through.

Basically, opening `cnn.com` and submitting the event are competing in the browser window.

Use a [hit callback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback), and set `window.location.href`, and you'll be fine:

```
ga('send', 'event', {
  'eventCategory': 'Links',
  'eventAction': 'Click',
  'hitCallback': function() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.cnn.com";
  }
});
```

This way, the browser will wait for the event to be submitted, and then access `cnn.com`.

Comment: Thank you for your post, Thomas. Three questions: 1. With your code, won't the cnn page open in the same window? It needs to open in a separate window. 2. What is the html code of the a object supposed to be? I'm assuming that the onclick code that I have will no longer be correct.

Comment: @oyvey 1. You might want to see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript Unfortunately, you'll probably be stopped by popup blockers. 2. It should be a function that calls the code I gave you.